# Why not instance variable?

Tags: java, instance-variables, variable-declaration

I'm relatively new to Java (I'm taking AP computer science) and the book I have, Big Java, poses this question:

> Consider the following implementation of a class Square:
>
> ```
> public class Square {
>
>     private int sideLength;
>
>     private int area; // Not a good idea
>
>     public Square(int length) {
>
>         sideLength = length; }
>
>     public int getArea() {
>
>         area = sideLength * sideLength;
>
>         return area; }
> }
> ```
>
> Why is it not a good idea to introduce an instance variable for the
>   area? Rewrite the class so that area is a local variable.

I'm sure the answer is obvious to a more experienced coder but I'm really unsure why making area an instance variable is a bad approach. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Because the area can't vary independently of the length... why make it a separate piece of state?

Comment: As previously stated, because it's redundant.

Comment: Even the local variable would be redundant.

Comment: As common rule a *getter* shouldn't have any **side effects**. A *getter* should return  a value, period, and not change the state of the object.

Comment: All the answers were great guys; I think I perfectly understand it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what (else) the author meant to say by that, one thing that I come up with is that it would just take up extra and redundant space in the memory each time you instantiate the object. Whereas you can write the simple method body as,

```
public int getArea() {
    return sideLength * sideLength;
}
```

This way, you don't take up any extra space in the memory, you send the calculation to CPU and get the results. Which is a good approach in real-world applications. For beginners, understanding the creation of variables, type-matching etc would be simpler to understand. Nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

Area is a value calculated from side length. Instance variables hold the object's *state* and if you include it there, you'll have to maintain two redundant pieces of state.

Including area as an instance variable would count as *caching* because you save the result instead of recalculating. This is sometimes desired, but not here because calculation is cheap enough.

Answer (score 2):

It's considered good practice to minimize the scope of variables.

This is because variables should only be available in contexts where you know the variable applies and has a useful value.

Here are two bugs that could be introduced because the scope is wider than it should be:

```
// This function compiles and looks correct, but only works if `getArea()`
// just happened to be called first. Otherwise, it returns 0.
int getVolume(int height) {
  return area * height;
}
```

If you minimized scope of `area` (by making it a local variable), this code wouldn't compile, and you wouldn't have this bug.

```
// This functions compiles and looks correct, but will sometimes return
// the area of a single side if another thread is trying to call getArea()
// at the same time, because both will overwrite the same variable.
int getCubeArea() {
  area = 6 * sideLength * sideLength;
  return area;
}
```

Again, if `area` instead was a local variable, you wouldn't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What other answers stated is actually correct, since area can be (easily) computed by knowing the sidelength, it makes no sense to keep track of it in a separate variable. Thats what the author means - *make the area variable local to its getter method*. You can do that by deleting the field declaration

`private int area;`

and declare you variable locally in your method, so in your getter:

`int area = sideLength * sideLength;
 return area;`

However keeping that field would make sense if you didnt want to repeat that computation each time
getArea() is called. In order to do that though, you need to take the computation out of the getter and put in the constructor.

**UPDATE**:

Following up on "that_other_guy" correct answer, neither of those bugs would happen if the area took its value in the constructor, everything would return the correct result